# Question about the Azure AD Application Proxy connector system requirements

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible/supported to install the Azure AD Application Proxy connector on Domain Controller (Active Directory domain services)?

I couldn't find any information on [the docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-connectors) about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Domain Controller refers to [Azure AD DS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview), the answer is no.

If it refers to on-premises AD DS, the answer is yes. But it also depends on your usage.

**Update:**

You need to meet the following prerequisites before beginning your implementation. You can see more information on setting up your environment, including these prerequisites, in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-add-on-premises-application).

Application Proxy reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-deployment-plan

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-connectors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-network-topology

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-high-availability-load-balancing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-security

Comment: Thank you @Tony. My question is intended for on-premises AD DS.
"depends on your usage" - Is there what factor? (for example?) Also, I am looking for official documents. Do you know that?

Comment: @Takeshi Which application you would like to use AAD APP proxy to publish? Is it a web app based on HTTP protocol?

Comment: Yes. I will publish the web app that works on the on-premises web server.

Comment: Thank you again, @Tony. I already checked prerequisites on the docs site. But I couldn't find any information about the support/unsupport install Azure AD Application Proxy connector **on** the Domain Controller (on-premises AD DS).

Comment: @Takeshi I have confirmed with Azure support engineer, the answer is 'yes' if you meet the prerequisites.